# Can I upgrade the new gear in Upper Blackrock Spire 6.0

Tags: world-of-warcraft

So along with the 6.0 patch we are given a preview version of the revamped Upper Blackrock Spire dungeon, the three bosses available drop blue gear with item level 550.

My question is can these pieces of gear be upgraded, and if so to what extent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, those items can not be upgraded. This is a precursor to the expansion where no items will be upgradedable.

Here is a [list](http://www.wowhead.com/items?filter=minle=550;maxle=550;cr=16;crs=7307;crv=0) of all items from the revamped Upper Blackrock Spire. If you check any of them you will see that there is no upgrade option.